# Changing span text with capybara

Tags: html, capybara

I've been using `Capybara` for 3 days now, and I have encountered a problem.

There is a html code:

```
<span id='some_id'> Text </span>
```

I need to change the Text with `Capybara`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `execute_script`:

```
page.execute_script("$('span#some_id').html('New Text');")
```

This assumes you have JQuery. If not, then substitute the script inside to whatever framework you're using.